# MongoDB aggregation - dynamic field path in $project

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I am trying to set the value of a new field in an aggregation `$project` stage equal to a field path that depends on another variable (different stock prices for different dates).

I am able to call this field path using a `getPrice` global helper for use in templates, but I cannot find any MongoDB pipeline operators that allow me to choose from many field paths in an aggregation (I see `$cond`, which only allows for two options).  I also see how to calculate values for a new field, but my use case does not require any calculations, the value already exists in the document.

This [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/NHAtncwB82h5GLrjP/Datepicker-and-Closing-Prices%20(AGG)%20v5) shows the issue I am having more clearly, but the most relevant code is below. What can I set as the value of `dynamicPrice` in $project?  Thank you.

```
//Document being aggregated
{
  ticker: "AAPL",
  eps: "9.20",
  lastPrice: "119.03",
  closingPrices: [
    {date: "2015-12-03", close: "115.20"},
    {date: "2015-12-04", close: "119.03"}
  ]
}

//Function to find price for selected date, in /common.js, works for templates
    getPrice = function(companyId) {
        var company = Companies.findOne({_id:companyId});
        var valuation = Template.parentData(1);
        var valuationDate = valuation.valuationDate;
        var valuationPrice = 0;
        _.each(company.closingPrices, function(closingPrices) {
            if (closingPrices.date == valuationDate) valuationPrice = closingPrices.close;
        });
        return valuationPrice;
    };

//$project stage of aggregation
           {
              $project: {
                _id: 1,
                eps: 1,
                lastPrice: 1,
                dynamicPrice: getPrice
              }
            }
```

[Edit: reduced text to simplify question]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this question with the use of `$unwind`.  The global helper `getPrice` was actually irrelevant for the aggregation.  Updated [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ntLLgKwZzwzKvRR4E/Datepicker-and-Closing-Prices%20(AGG-FINAL)) here.

```
//Documents being aggregated
{
  ticker: "AAPL",
  eps: "9.20",
  lastPrice: "119.03",
  closingPrices: [
    {date: "2015-12-03", close: "115.20"},
    {date: "2015-12-04", close: "119.03"}
  ]
},
//...more documents

//Aggregation
var valuation = Valuations.findOne({_id: valuationId});
var valuationDate = valuation.valuationDate;

var pipeline = [
        {
          $unwind: "$closingPrices"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            "closingPrices.date": valuationDate
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            eps: 1,
            lastPrice: 1,
            dynamicPrice: "$closingPrices.close"
          }
        }
        //...$group stage with calculations
```